# My cells are getting duplicated to apply the changes i make on the online database

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

with this code i am able to get a snapshot of my database and load the data into a tableView. However, when i try to make a change to the online database i get duplicated cells that apply the change instead of the normal cells applying this change.

```
    // Create reference to databse
    ref = Database.database().reference()

    // Retrieve data from firebase database and listen for changes
    ref.child("Clubs").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        print("clubs: \(snapshot)")

        if(snapshot.exists()) {
            let array:NSArray = snapshot.children.allObjects as NSArray

            for obj in array {
                let snapshot:DataSnapshot = obj as! DataSnapshot
                if let childSnapshot = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                    print("myClubs: \(childSnapshot)")

                    if let clubName = childSnapshot["name"] as? String, let banner = childSnapshot["bannerImage"] as? String {
                        print(clubName)
                        print(banner)

                        let club = Club(name: clubName, image: banner)
                        print("new club success: \(club)")
                        self.nightClubs.append(club)
                    }
                }
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        }

    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever any value in `Clubs` changes, you're executing the code inside the listener. The code appends the clubs to the `nightClubs` array, but doesn't clear it. You need to empty the array before repopulating:

```
// Retrieve data from firebase database and listen for changes
    ref.child("Clubs").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        print("clubs: \(snapshot)")
        self.nightClubs.removeAll() // empty array before adding values

        ...
```

Comment: Thank you Jen! Literally just saved my life

Comment: Glad to help! If this answered worked for you, then please accept it. Thanks!